# Azure Blob Download Task Editor

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to download files from Azure Blob Storage to local PC(then SQL server), I use the "Azure Blob Download Task Editor" component in an SSIS package. It works well. But I have to input a static "BlobContainer" name. The issue is I have plenty of containers in it. How Can I write that field as a dynamic value? How can I get all the Blob Containers name?

[image: Screen shot attached]

Answer (score 0):

As per this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a9067dd6-ccd9-4805-835d-523323068b0b/when-use-quotazure-blob-download-task-editorquot-component-in-an-ssis-package-is-it-possible-to?forum=sqlintegrationservices), it can be done by using `Execute SQL Task` and `Foreach Loop Container`, But you should manually fetch the containers' name from azure and store in database.

Use Execute SQL Task extract Container names, and store them in a Object Type variable(like: NameSet)

Use Foreach Loop Container to extract each name from the NameSet and store the value into containers variable, which you have created.

The package should look like below:

[image]